# What does it mean for the continuum function to be eventually constant below k?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am following a Thomas Jech's "Set Theory" and in Chapter 5 have come across the following:

> We take the Continuum Function to be $2^k$, without assuming the GCH: Generalized Continuum Hypothesim
>
> **Corollary 5.17**
>
> If $k$ is a singular cardinal and if the continuum **function** is eventually constant bellow $k$, with value $\lambda $, then $2^k$.

I am having some trouble understanding exactly what Jech means when he says "if the continuum function is eventually constant"? I am sorry I cannot offer much more into the discussion, since I am simply stuck on the wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then

"The continuum function is eventually constant below $\kappa,$ with value $\lambda\!"$

means

"There exists $\gamma\lt\kappa$ such that for all $\delta,$ if $\gamma \lt \delta \lt \kappa,$ then $2^\delta=\lambda.\!"$

Answer (score 1):

You’ve misread it: it says *if the continuum **function** is eventually constant below* $\kappa$, *with value* $\lambda$. This means that there is a $\mu$ such that $\operatorname{cf}\kappa\le\mu<\kappa$, and $2^\nu=2^\mu=\lambda$ for $\mu\le\nu<\kappa$. This can be abbreviated the way Jech does in the first sentence of the proof: there is a $\mu$ such that $\operatorname{cf}\kappa\le\mu<\kappa$ and $2^{<\kappa}=2^\mu=\lambda$.

Comment: Urg tired eyes on the check, sorry about that.

Comment: Ah ok, I assume that the only time where the continuum function is NOT constant would be for regular cardinals where there does not exist such a cardinal between $k$ and its cofinality $cf(k)$?
Also, meta type question here as I am new; since this question was very closed and unlikely to help anyone but myself, would you recommend deleting?

Comment: @Max: You could still have, for instance, $2^\kappa=2^{(\kappa^+)}=\kappa^{++}$, where $\kappa^+$ is certainly regular. Or the continuum function could be nowhere constant, as happens with $\mathsf{GCH}$. \\ No, there’s no reason to delete; you never know when something might be useful to someone.